# Error Code 90161 Invalid provisioning profile

Tags: app-store-connect

I've developed an Xamarin Forms App and want to publish on App Store.

Have bought Apple Developer Program for 99$

I have created IPA using Visual Studio in ad-hoc mode and selected Distribution Identity and Distribution profile. But while uploading get the following error

> ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile.The provisioning
>   profile included in the bundle x.x.x.x[Payload/x.x.x.app] is
>   invalid.[Missing code-signing certificate.] For more information,visit
>   the iOS developer Portal."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get this error, you probably don't have the correct type of Provisioning Profile. There's a few types of Provisioning Profiles, most notably are the "Development" and "Distribution" profiles. I suggest looking at your provisioning profiles, and if necessary recreate them.

You have to use App Store (not Ad-hoc) provisioning Profile while creating your .ipa in order to upload to App Store with Application Loader.

Try this, and see if that helps. Be sure to haul the new profiles in Xcode (or any other method you'd use) and edit your project's settings.

Comment: Copy paste of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960751/error-code-90161-invalid-provisioning-profile

Still doesn't answer what "haul the new profiles" means.